# How to rewrite $resource factory as a class in ES6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm rewriting all my AngularJs code in ES6. I have a User service that is a factory which returns the `$resource` object:

```
angular.module('cdcApp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
      id: '@_id'
    },
    {
      changePassword: {
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
          controller:'password'
        }
      },
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          id:'me'
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

It has been rewritten as the following:

```
class User {
  constructor($resource) {
    this.$resource = $resource;
    this.resource = this.$resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
      id: '@_id'
    }, {
      changePassword: {
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
          controller: 'password'
        }
      },
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          id: 'me'
        }
      }
    });

  }
}
angular.module('cdcApp')
  .service('User', User);
```

However, it broke my old controller as I must use `User.resource` instead of just normal `User` as usual. Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: A factory is not a class. Why would you want to write it using `class` syntax?

Comment: @Bergi That's why I rewrote it as a service instead of factory.

Comment: But you *want* a factory that returns a resource, don't you? There was nothing wrong with the code you had, no need to rewrite it.

Comment: Alright. I just wanted to know if there is somehow I could return some kind of "factory" using class in ES6. Based on your response, it seems like I can't, can I? BTW, Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
export default class Factory {
  constructor (API_ENDPOINT, $resource) {
    return $resource(API_ENDPOINT + "/url", {id: "@id"}, {
      update: {
        method: "PUT"
      }
    });
  }
  static activate(API_ENDPOINT, $resource) {
    Factory.instance = new Factory(API_ENDPOINT, $resource);
    return Factory.instance;
  }
}

Factory.$inject = ["API_ENDPOINT", "$resource"];
```

then in your module:

```
import Factory from "path_to_your_factory_file";
angular.module(name, [ngResource]).factory("Factory", Factory.activate);
```

Enjoy!